# Need help turning pandas dataframe into multiindex by grouping just one column.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
>>>df
group A B C
1     1 2 3
1     2 3 6
1     4 9 9
2     8 1 2
2     5 6 4
3     6 5 7
```

I would like it multi-indexed so it looks like

```
group 
      A B C
1     1 2 3
      2 3 6
      4 9 9
2     8 1 2
      5 6 4
3     6 5 7
```

I'd like to access each group number gives me a dataframe of just the values for that group index. What I mean is if I type `df[0]` then I get

```
>>>df[0]
A B C
1 2 3
2 3 6
4 9 9
```

and I can do the usual functions, like take the mean via `df[0].mean()`

I'm sure this is possible but reading the pandas help pages and looking through forums seems to have solutions for people who already created multi-indexed dataframes with tuples.

Answer (score 2):

`set_index` will do this for you.

```
df = df.set_index('group').set_index(
    df.groupby('group').cumcount(), append=True
)

df
         A  B  C
group           
1     0  1  2  3
      1  2  3  6
      2  4  9  9
2     0  8  1  2
      1  5  6  4
3     0  6  5  7
```

Alternatively, create a `MultiIndex` object and assign to `df.index`. This is a lot more efficient in terms of memory.

```
i = df['group']
j = df.groupby(df.pop('group')).cumcount()

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([i, j])
```

And now,

```
df.xs(1)

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  6
2  4  9  9
```

Just Like That™.

---

If you don't fancy the `xs` at the end, there's certainly the option of splitting your DataFrame into groups and dumping each one into a dictionary.

The `groupby` API has been written to mimic the `itertools.groupby` dict-like idiom, here's what that looks like:

```
df_dict = {k : g for k, g in df.drop('group', 1).groupby(df.group)}
df_dict[1]

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  6
2  4  9  9
```

Note that this is no longer a single DataFrame, but a *dictionary* of them.

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know why you've spat on this answer. Your feedback will help me correct any mistakes. Thank you.

Comment: This works! BUT!!! It's awfully complicated, as I hope you will agree. It would certainly be nice if there were a much shorter method. It would also be useful to not have to refer to the groupings with df.xs() but via a standard df[column]. By the way, I didn't downvote!

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Thank you, I appreciate your support. You can count on me to return the favour :)

Comment: @AstroBen Edited with a much more efficient solution.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, these are all awesome answers. Do you know whether there is some way to do this and not have to use the `df.xs()` to access the groupings, but rather one could just use `df[1]` or something like that?

Comment: @AstroBen No, and I will explain why. For indexing multiIndexes in the manner you want, you will need to provide `slice` objects. However, slices are not hashable, so this does not work directly. You will need to go through an accessor like `loc` or `xs` to extract slices. 
The alternative would be keeping a dictionary of groupby objects. Wait, let me edit again :p

Comment: @AstroBen I've edited. If you are not satisfied with this, then xs and loc are your only other options.

Comment: @COLDSPEED, I just tried `df.set_index('group',inplace=True)` and `df.xs(1)` also returns a usable dataframe, just without the unique integer index on the left.

Comment: @AstroBen Aside from the fact that that's NOT a multiIndex (your question seemed to indicate you knew what you wanted),  repeating/non-unique indices are generally discouraged, they tend to cause issues later down the road. Although if that's what you want ...

Comment: @COLDSPEED, thanks. I think I understand now. I appreciate this a lot. I'm marking this as the answer.